# App does not launch on emulator/device using appium

Tags: appium

Im new to appium and planning to use it for unity game automation. However I cant seem to find how the application will be launched on the emulator/device? Below are the steps I have done

1. Start the emulator or connect the device (since only one should be connected)
2. Launch the appium server using the appium app
3. Ran the python script from a terminal

I am trying it with the contact manager example app. Below is the python code

```
import os
from time import sleep

from selenium import webdriver

# Returns abs path relative to this file and not cwd
PATH = lambda p: os.path.abspath(
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), p)
)

desired_caps = {}
desired_caps['device'] = 'Android'
desired_caps['browserName'] = ''
desired_caps['version'] = '4.2'
desired_caps['app'] = PATH('/Users/<uname>/Downloads/ContactManager.apk')
desired_caps['app-package'] = 'com.example.android.contactmanager'
desired_caps['app-activity'] = '.ContactManager'
driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)

print driver.get_window_size()
```

Below is the log from the appium app

```
info: Using local app from desiredCaps: /Users/ears/Downloads/ContactManager.apk

debug: Request received with params: {"sessionId":null,"desiredCapabilities":{"app-package":"com.example.android.contactmanager","app":"/Users/<uname>/Downloads/ContactManager.apk","browserName":"","version":"4.2","device":"Android","app-activity":".ContactManager"}}
debug: Using fast reset? true

info: Creating new appium session 250e7bfd-92bf-4b2a-894c-f4a0e2d02ce7
info: Starting android appium
info: Preparing device for session
info: Checking whether app is actually present
info: Checking whether adb is present

debug: Appium request initiated at /wd/hub/status

info: Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"0.15.0","revision":"a7b47d73a27074cc928cc5b325e5d4de1b6e5594"}},"sessionId":"250e7bfd-92bf-4b2a-894c-f4a0e2d02ce7"}

debug: Request received with params: {}

GET /wd/hub/status 200 1ms - 199b
```

Where can I find detailed log? It does not launch the app on the emulator. Im on a Mac and this is for Android.
Am I missing something trivial here?

Answer (score 2):

I had incorrectly set to the path variable to

```
..../sdk/tools/
```

instead of

```
..../sdk/
```

Changing this fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue in your code is highlighted by reading the appium log, particularly this line:

`debug: Request received with params: {"sessionId":null,"desiredCapabilities":{"app-package":"com.example.android.contactmanager","app":"/Users//Downloads/ContactManager.apk","browserName":"","version":"4.2","device":"Android","app-activity":".ContactManager"}} debug: Using fast reset? true`

You can see it includes the path `/Users//Downloads/ContactManager.apk`, which is not a valid path. Looks like you need to change `<uname>` in your code to an actual string.